# What does this nested set of braces/brackets in JS/Node mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I usually program in C# (or C++) and I am now reading Node.js (without much background in JavaScript).

I am having a hard time understanding this:

```
var db = {
  users: [
    { name: 'tobi' },
    { name: 'loki' },
    { name: 'jane' }
  ]
};
```

What is this? Is this an array? a map? a dictionary?

Comment: `db` is an object which contains one key-value pair, whose value is an array of objects

Comment: its JS object hope this basic tutorial may help you https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp

Comment: db is a variable that has an object assigned to it. An object is sort of similar to a dictionary in other languages. Primarily it’s a key value store. That object has a key of users, and the value of that key is an array of objects that all have a key of name and a string value. Here’s an example of how to use that `db.users[2].name` would give you “jane”.

Comment: Oh, and the question of JavaScript vs Node.js. JavaScript is a language that traditionally ran in browsers but now also runs on servers. “Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform JavaScript run-time environment that executes JavaScript code server-side.” Hopefully that clears some things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var db` is declaring a new variable called `db`. It's loosely defining the variable as an object as it's wrapped in {} brackets. In JavaScript this can be access either by dot notation (db.users) or bracket notation (db['users']).

Next, you have a property called `users`. This is loosely defined as an array as it's wrapped in square brackets []. Users then has properties inside where the values are just strings.

Some examples of how you might access these values:

```
db.users.0.name
db['users'][0]['name']
db.users[0].name
```

JavaScript is a loosely typed language and more often than not any `type` can be converted/changed at anytime. Unless you're getting into ES6 of course. However if you're just getting started with JS, I suggest avoiding ES6 for now :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly equivalent to an anonymous type in C#:

```
var db = new {
  users = new[] {
    new {name = "tobi"},
    new {name = "loki"},
    new {name = "jane"}
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is known as an object/dictionary. It is called `db`, and it contains a single property `users`, which is an array of anonymous objects with the key-value pair `name:`***`string`***.